# Alternative to Files#copy() in Java 6

Tags: java, file-io

So this is the code I have, which already works:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        String pathToFile = "myimage.jpg";
        File file = new File(pathToFile);
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
        response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"");
        Files.copy(file.toPath(), response.getOutputStream());
        response.flushBuffer();
    }
}
```

However, I must make this work with JDK 1.6.

Files.copy is only available with Java 1.7.

Any suggestions?

Comment: By the way, response.flushBuffer() is totally unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Apache commons IOutils.

```
IOUtils.copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Java 6 didn’t comes with any ready make file copy function, you have to manual create the file copy process. To copy file, just convert the file into a bytes stream with FileInputStream and write the bytes into another file with FileOutputStream.

As there's no way to do this a lot easier with JDK methods.You could use **IOUtils** from [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html), it also has a lot of other useful things.

```
IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
```

Or else using [Guava's](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html) ByteStreams.copy() you can achieve the same functionality.

```
ByteStreams.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
```